# Assert content of cell based on content of a cell in the same row with Cypress

Tags: html-table, cypress

I just started using Cypress for test automation to see if I like it but I running into a small problem. I want to assert the content of a cell based on a value in another cell in the same row. In the example below the first row contains a user that has finished registering, the cells are all filled. On the second row a new account is visible which has not yet been completed by the user. Cells such as first name and last name are still empty. Display: -
Now I want to verify that the first cell of the row containing 'usermanagementtest@test.com' in the third column contains '-'. There is no way for me to know on what row this will be displayed.

I start by asserting there is a cell visible containing the given email address:

```
cy.get('.module-user--list tr').find('td').contains('usermanagementtest@lukkien.com').should('be.visible')
```

but now I would like to assert the value of the first column on that same row.

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>j.doe@test.com</td>
            <td>0321654987</td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>usermanagementtest@test.com</td>
            <td>-</td>
        </tr>       
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a colleague I achieved this by:

```
cy.get('.module-user--list tr').find('td').contains('usermanagementtest@test.com').prev().prev().should('contain', '-')
```

Another way would be to get the parent element and find your way from there:

```
cy.get('.module-user--list tr').find('td').contains('usermanagementtest@test.com').parent().as('row')
cy.get('@row').find('td:nth-child(1)').should('contain', 'foo')
```